# How to mock params in routing in angular (jasmine)

Tags: angular, jasmine

How mock params

```
this.id = params['id'];
```

(router angular) in test in jasmine?

My code:

```
constructor(public activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute, private store: Store) { }
          
ngOnInit(): void {
  this.store.dispatch(new LoadCategoriesAction());
  this.store.dispatch(new LoadProductsByMainAction(false));
  this.sub = this.activatedRoute.params.subscribe(params => {
    this.id = params['id'];
    console.log("!!!!!!!!!!!!!");
    console.log(this.id);
    if (this.id) {
      this.store.dispatch(new LoadProductByIdAction(this.id));
    }
  })
}
```

Comment: Did you read https://angular.io/guide/testing-components-scenarios#routed-components?

Answer (score 1):

You've to create a mock for ActivatedRoute, something like below;

```
providers: [
...,
{provide: ActivatedRoute, useValue: {params: of({id: '123'})}}
]
```